# Varnish Cache don't show Apache Website

Tags: magento, caching, varnish, varnish-vcl

I install Magento on Apache and now want to Cache the Magento Shop so I have to install Varnish Cache and change the port like tutorial here [Visit](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-and-configure-varnish-with-apache-on-ubuntu-12-04--3), but after doing that I only see the Example Varnish site not my Magento Shop. The changes which I made are equal to the tutorial.

So how can I change it so that I can see my Shop again and cache it also?(Varnish is running)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're missing some changes on your vhost, so you're seeing only apache's default vhost.

Try:

```
$ sudo sed -i 's/:80>/:8080>/' /etc/apache2/sites-available/*
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: tried it but also not working its the same  It works!

This is the default web page for this server.

The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.

Comment: so shows me the file on apache /var/www but I use Plesk an create it so that my shop files are /var/www/vhosts/shop.domain.com/httpdocs/

Comment: Ohh, you use plesk... You should find in plesk where to switch HTTP port to 8080. I guess Plesk has configured your vhost to listen only on the public IP (and you are using de loopback IP as backend)